# SQL Select Statement Where Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause

> List first name, last name and course id for all students that are in
>   a course controlled by either Tony Richardson, Dennis Viehland or Kay
>   Fielden.  Order your output in ascending order of course ID.

I am preparing for an SQL test by doing a practice set of questions of which the above is one. I have an answer for the following using a where clause like this for the names:

```
where SF_F_Name in ('Tony','Dennis','Kay') and SF_L_Name in ('Richardson','Viehland','Fielden')
```

I've been trying to find a way to look for the specific combinations of the first and the last name as this kind of where clause could, potentially, return a "Kay Richardson". How could this be achieved? I haven't been able to find any examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pointed out the flaw in your `WHERE` clause yourself.  Just check for full names individually to avoid this problem:

```
WHERE (SF_F_Name = 'Tony'   AND SF_L_Name = 'Richardson') OR
      (SF_F_Name = 'Dennis' AND SF_L_Name = 'Viehland') OR
      (SF_F_Name = 'Kay'    AND SF_L_Name = 'Fielden')
```

You could also concatenate the first and last name columns together and then check for the full name using a single `WHERE IN`:

```
WHERE SF_F_NAME || ' ' || SF_L_Name IN
    ('Tony Richardson', 'Dennis Viehland', 'Kay Fielden')
```

Comment: Ah - I was hoping there was a cleaner way of doing it rather than needing to explicitly state every part of the OR like that

Comment: There is a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is exactly what I thought should be possible but didn't know how to achieve.

Comment: Most of the time I have either used or seen `WHERE IN` clauses, it has been with a single column so your problem never comes up.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL this can be written as:

```
where (SF_F_Name, SF_L_Name) IN (  ('Tony', Richardson'),
                                   ('Dennis', Viehland), 
                                   ('Kay','Fielden')
                                 )
```

This is supported (at least) in Postgres, Oracle and DB2

Comment: That explains a lot of my problem. I had tried this previously but we are being forced to use MS Access for this test for... who the hell knows why? -_-